# How to adjust BitBucket merge strategies to have correct date on commits?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I was trying to debug an issue recently introduced in our codebase, however I am having troubles to understand the git history as displayed by BitBucket.

For example, we have commits that were merged today however BitBucket is showing the commits as dated from 3 weeks ago?

How to fix the date displayed?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a misunderstanding in how Git merge works, or perhaps what author and commit dates represent, but asking "How to fix the date displayed?" is a strange way to word something that is working as intended. A merge is by definition not going to change anything about a commit, because doing so would change the commit ID. If for some reason you want to rewrite your commits and change the dates they show, you can do that, but that's not "fixing" something, it's just modifying the history to match what you wish to see.

Comment: Take a look at `git log --graph` and see if you prefer that. Also, I think `git log --first-parent` may be of interest to you. It shows you when the code was merged in, and comparing the first parent merge commit with the previous first parent merge commit will show you the set of code that was merged in at that time. (This is equivalent to what you'd get if you use a squash merge, except with regular merge you keep the history of the commits in that merge as well, which you see with the regular log.)

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR This is an issue with the default BitBucket merge strategy.

Go to `settings` -> `merge strategy`, change the default merge strategy from "merge commit" to "rebase and fast-forward".

[image: bitbucket screenshot]

**merge commit**: The default strategy is "merge commit" and it's a bad default. The PR will add the commits with the original date the commits were created.

For example if you were working on a fix 2 weeks ago, that is finally merged today. Your commit has a date of 2 weeks ago when it was initially done. When the PR is merged, BitBucket will rewrite the history to add the commit with the date of 2 weeks ago (although it happened today), and BitBucket will add a placeholder merge commit with a date of today (to indicate a merge happened today).

End result, the commit is in the past up between other commits that happened over the past weeks. It's extremely confusing to understand when any code was really shipped.

**rebase and merge**: This is the sane equivalent of "merge commit" and would have been a better default. The rebase implies that the commit date is refreshed to the time of the merge. There is an extra placeholder merge commit to indicate a merge was done.

**rebase and fast-forward**: The commit date is refreshed to the time of the merge. There is no extra placeholder merge commit. The merge commit is unnecessary, it's a duplicate of the last commit message. This is the simplest mode and typically what developers would expect when merging.

NOTE: It's the same as "rebase and merge" without the extra merge commit. Either strategy is a reasonable default and is equivalent, depending on your opinion on having or not having an extra merge commit.

**squash**: The squash strategy will squash all the commits from the PR into a single commit. It's implicitly making a rebase and a new commit at the time of merge. The commit messages are merged together and the result can be unexpected. Personally I find it nicer to use the "Squash" button on a PR and enter a meaningful commit message.

WARNING ON SQUASH: The squash mode by default will combine and obliterate commit messages in unexpected ways. Try in a test repo and see what you get. There is a very important setting "Max Summary" that you probably want to set to "0".

**How to go about fixing the merge strategy organization wide**: You might find that your team or organization is having regular issue with identifying when a bug was shipped because the git history is incomprehensible. You can alleviate the pain by adjusting the merge strategy, however people might be change-averse and reluctant to edit BitBucket settings (git is a never-ending can of worms!). You can take it gradually. First, you correct the merge strategy from "merge commit" to "rebase and merge", it's the same thing but sane. Developers will get used to it and realize it's better. After some months they will notice and ask about the duplicate merge commits, and that's when you correct to the merge strategy "rebase and fast-forward".